# Profit maximization through differentiation (cattle)

Tags: derivatives

Each cow weighs 300kg. The cost of maintaining a cow is 20€ per day. The rate of change of the cows weight is 4kg a day. The market price is currently 50€ per kg and it is falling 50 cents a day. How much time should the cattleman wait to sell the cows? How much extra money does he make by waiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:
$$ W = 300 + 4d, $$
$$ P = 50W - \frac{d}{2} - 20d, $$
Plug the expression for $W$ into the expression for $P$ and obtain an expression for $P$ in terms of $d$. Differentiate this and set to $0$ to find the maximum.